# Debugging a MySQL query permanently affects the execution time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to debug a simple but very slow running MySQL query on a table with a JOIN to a very large table (13m rows), the large table has multiple indexes.

The join is very basic, just a join from ID on the small table to foreign_ID on the big table.

This query has been fast to run in the past, however a lot of new data has been added since then. It took 30ms to run previously, it now takes 5 minutes.

On live, I tried repairing the large table by using an alter command to set it to InnoDb. But this made no difference.

So to debug the query, I run EXPLAIN and try removing the joins etc until the query runs very quickly again.

**The join types started out as ALL, eq_ref, ref and ref.**

Then as I re-enable joins and to try to find a way of making it work in a performant way I find that actually now, the ORIGINAL QUERY now works quickly again.

The only thing that has changed is the query execution plan.

**The join types are now range, eq_ref, eq_ref and ref.**

What happened? Why is MySQL now treating this same query differently to how it did before?

And how can I make my live server do this too? And how can I stop this from happening again in the future?

EDIT: MySQL version on prod and locally is 5.7

Comment: When there are different execution plans the queries are different. it runs ar deterministic procedure, that we can fofce keys to test different Indexes.

Comment: what is your mysql version?

Comment: mysql is 5.7 on server and locally

Comment: @nbk Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. The issue I am facing is the same query having different execution plans on different servers. And in fact the execution plan also changed on my local machine.

Comment: @JonWinstanley were everything identical? data and querys?
please check how [query-cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html) works

Comment: in the code mysql has to select one of many keys/indexes and soemtimes it got it wrong. Check the the minor numbers because 5.7.15 and 5.7.29 cqn differ in many ways, you should when thequery is slow a see which uindex mysql is using and choose for testing purposes another one. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be falling foul of a query planner bug that frequently manifests on MySQL 5.7 and later. What happens is that the query planner will decide on the wrong execution plan (indexes, join order), which results in the same query on the same data set sometimes running quickly (with the correct execution plan) or slowly (with the wrong execution plan, often resulting in a full table scan). I have seen this happen on every MySQL 5.7 and 8.0 deployment I have worked on. On MySQL 5.6 and earlier and MariaDB, this sort of behaviour from the query planner is only provocable by having an unusually large number of indexes on a table (10+). So if you have a lot of indexes on one of the tables involved, it my be worth trying to rationalize the number of them down.

Apart from keeping the number of indexes on each table as low as you reasonably can, you have two options to address this:

1) When you identify queries that encounter this bug, constrain them using index hints (USE/FORCE INDEX (index_name)) and, if necessary, STRAIGHT_JOIN to force the JOIN ordering.

2) Switch to MariaDB which doesn't seem to suffer from this problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Really helpful info. Sounds likely too, as this has only happened since we upgraded to 5.7. Will look into it further.